# Does .Net framework 4.5.2 support gcp?

Tags: c#-4.0, google-cloud-platform, asp.net-mvc-5, google-cloud-datastore

I have MVC web application developed on dotnet  framework 4.5.2 . This application has database in MS SQL server. I want to move DB from SQL server to GCP. Does .Net framework 4.5.2 support GCP? Or i will have to rewrite application in dotnet core with MVC .
I have gone through several blogs  many of them has contradictory conclusion but all of these blogs  specify that dotnet core supports GCP and hence I am not able to reach on conclusion whether dotnet framework 4.5.2 supports GCP or not. Does anyone has idea about this or any reference.

Comment: .NET doesn't support GCP. GCP might support .NET.

Comment: Have you looked at the product page - https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/ ?

Comment: There's also some information here - https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploy-dotnet-applications

Comment: I think there is some libraries in .Net core, because it's open source and Google like it. But I don't know the level of support, update, compliance with current API..

Answer (score 0):

There are some diferentes ways to deploy an app in GCP. You can take a look in the following official documentation  [Compute Engine with .NET](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/hello-world), [App Engine with .NET](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/quickstart), [Kubernetes with .NET](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart) and [APIs and .NET](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/).